# Poor Query performance when scalar variables used in Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, parameter-sniffing, query-performance

Facing a strange issue that a query runs incredibly slow (worse) when scalar variables are used as parameter.

**Actual Query (Faster) - 9 secs**

```
select
  sum(v.sale_value) as col_0_0_,
  sum(v.vat_value)  as col_1_0_,
  sum(v.sale_fcy)   as col_2_0_,
  sum(v.vat_fcy)    as col_3_0_
from my_view v
where v.company_id = 1 and v.filing_year = 2018 and v.filing_month = 1;
```

**Parameterized Query (Worse) - 16 mins**

```
DECLARE @P0 int, @P1 int, @P2 int;
SET @P0 = 1;
SET @P1 = 2018;
SET @P2 = 1;
select
  sum(v.sale_value) as col_0_0_,
  sum(v.vat_value)  as col_1_0_,
  sum(v.sale_fcy)   as col_2_0_,
  sum(v.vat_fcy)    as col_3_0_
from my_view v
where v.company_id = @P0 and v.filing_year = @P1 and v.filing_month = @P2;
```

Execution times for both queries were calculated by executing in command line client (IntelliJ Database console).

Query with this scalar variable is generated by our Hibernate Application as we've used `setParameter(String name, Object value)` to set the param values.

First, we suspected issue in hibernate generated query, but narrowed down to SQL Server query execution after identifying it as parameterized query using `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`. Does query optimiser get confused when scalar variables are used?

In java code, we're setting the values as query parameters. In `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`, the actual query is:

```
(@P0 int,@P1 int,@P2 int)select <columns> from my_view v
where v.company_id= @P0 and v.filing_year= @P1 and v.filing_month= @P2
```

**Note:** `my_view` is pretty complex (nested views, group by, joins, order by, where clause...). We tried to compare the execution plans, but they're incredibly huge We are looking into it but might take some time.

If I run the slow query with `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, it executes in 9 secs.

**SQL Server Version**

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
    Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Look at the execution plan in xml format. In the down of the file check ParameterList node - are the values such as expected?

Comment: Are the actual data fields all `int` fields? I have encountered problems with query plan generation in this type of query when the values passed in are not the same data type as the values in the database. If the field is tinyint, use a tinyint parameter, and so on.